# nodejs mysql multiple where query's

Tags: mysql, node.js

I've been working with mysql in nodejs for a bit and I can't seem to figure out how to use the query with multiple where statements.
Like:

SELECT * FROM user_information WHERE a=a or b=b

Right now i have this as my code:

```
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM user_information WHERE username=" + registerarray[1] + " OR email=" + registerarray[3],function(err, results){
            if (err){console.error(err);}
    });
```

Thank you and best regards

Me

Answer (score 1):

`results` is rows of response from mysql.

Let's simplify parts:

```
const 
  q = "SELECT * FROM user_information WHERE username=? OR email=?", // You can use placeholders like ? marks 
  args = [registerarray[1], registerarray[3]]; // array of values that will be set to placeholders (will be escaped for security)
connection
  .query(
    q, // our query
    args,  // placeholder values
    (err, records) => { // query response scope begins here
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }

      console.log('THIS IS RESULT OF QUERY EXECUTION:');
      console.log(records); // this is result, already fetched array
    });
```