# Query in Mysql and Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have this Mysql query that is working fine. However, I need to add 2 more conditions and I'm not sure how to do this.

```
//index.js

module.exports = {
    getHomePage: (req, res) => {

       let query ='SELECT Tbl_Email_mensagens.codigo AS Codigo, Tbl_Email_mensagens.mensagem AS Mensagem,Tbl_Email_mensagens.celular AS Celular, cm_custmaster.fullname AS NomeCompleto FROM Tbl_Email_mensagens LEFT JOIN cm_custmaster ON Tbl_Email_mensagens.celular = cm_custmaster.mobile';

        // execute query
        db.query(query, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                res.redirect('/');
            }
            res.render('index.ejs', {
                title: ""
                ,players: result
            });
        });
    },
};
```

I then need to add these 2 conditions:

```
Where group = '7' and send = '0'
```

Very thanks!

Comment: What tables these fields are from?

Comment: @Akina:  Tbl_Email_mensagens

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodejs mysql multiple where query's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43575942/nodejs-mysql-multiple-where-querys)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Tbl_Email_mensagens.codigo AS Codigo, 
       Tbl_Email_mensagens.mensagem AS Mensagem,
       Tbl_Email_mensagens.celular AS Celular, 
       cm_custmaster.fullname AS NomeCompleto 
FROM Tbl_Email_mensagens 
LEFT JOIN cm_custmaster ON Tbl_Email_mensagens.celular = cm_custmaster.mobile
WHERE Tbl_Email_mensagens.`group` = 7 
  AND Tbl_Email_mensagens.send = 0
```

Pay attention - the word `group` is reserved one, so it **MUST** be wrapped into backticks. But it is more safe to rename it, to some `group_number`, for example.

Whereas the quotes over the values are excess (you may store them if according field has any string datatype).

Comment: Please,
Now, i need to limit the number of characters displayed in the query 'Tbl_Email_mensagens.messagem AS Message' to just 40 characters.
Thank you again

Comment: @MikailhP [LEFT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) function.

Comment: LEFT(Tbl_Email_mensagens.mensagem,40) AS Mensagem 
Thanks again